# Keybase sponsored this puzzle

Tags: cipher

Yesterday I found a note under my chair. The note seemed very mysterious so I thought there must be a hidden meaning inside. It read:

> OJNU OJNU OJNU V YVGRENYYL FGBYR XRLONFR'F PBQR NAQ CBFGRQ VG FBZRJURER RYFR YBY
>
> - moonlit diner stylized steerable kooky stature anagram calm flaxseed outshine muppet herbicide curling
> - yqZPxE

What could the hidden message be?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: any hints for this?

Answer (score 2):

The first line translates to-

> BWAH BWAH BWAH I LITERALLY STOLE KEYBASE'S CODE AND POSTED IT SOMEWHERE ELSE LOL , using ROT13

The rest not sure yet.